# visual basic 2008 generate text box on click

Tags: vb.net, events

I have created the text box, and the generate button. 
when I click on the generate button, I want it to display a text box with numbers. How do I do so using the event handler?. Sorry, basic question.

Comment: When the generate button is clicked, you want to display a number in the text box that already exists on the form, right?

Comment: Hi, first you need add a textbox and i little bit code 
if you add a textbox, then add code for add text on textbox property .text what language are you using vb or c# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all that you are trying to do is to set the value of a text box when a button is clicked, then you can do it like in the following example.  You'll have to replace the names of the controls with whatever you have called them:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static count As Integer = 0
    count += 1
    Select Case count
        Case 1
            TextBox1.Text = "123"
        Case 2
            TextBox1.Text = "345"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I would like to add another functionality that is, when I click on the button the value 123 gets generated. When I click on it again, I would like it to generate another value say 345. How do I do that using that? Using switch case?

Answer (score 0):

First, drag a `TextBox` from your tool box, then double-click on your button and edit your `Button1_Click` method, like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   TextBox1.Text = "12234234234"
End Sub
```